# How can I add an empty line after a certain linenumber within a text file?

Tags: python, file, line, addition

I got a file with 100 lines. I want to delete line 26 till 49 so I did:

```
import os
l1 = []
with open(r"C:work001.txt", 'r') as fp:
    l1 = fp.readlines()
with open(r"C:work001.txt", 'w') as fp:
    for number, line in enumerate(l1):
        if number not in list (range(25, 49)):
            fp.write(line)
```

After doing this, the 26th line till 49th line are deleted. But now I want to add an empty line after the 25th line. How can I do that?

Comment: A tip: you don't need to generate a list here since it uses some of your memory `if number not in list (range(25, 49))`, you can simply do `if number > 48 or number < 25`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
import os
l1 = []
with open(r"C:work001.txt", 'r') as fp:
    l1 = fp.readlines()
with open(r"C:work001.txt", 'w') as fp:
    for line in l1[:25]:
        fp.write(line)
    fp.write("\n")
    for line in l1[49:]:
        fp.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

This task is simple because you already have the line number:

```py
import os
l1 = []
with open(r"C:work001.txt", 'r') as fp:
    l1 = fp.readlines()

with open(r"C:work001.txt", 'w') as fp:
    for number, line in enumerate(l1):
        if number not in list (range(25, 49)):
            fp.write(line)
        if number == 24:
            fp.write('\n')
```

This code write an empty line after the 25th line, since the `enumerate` function count starts from zero, so we check `if number == 24`, and it's after you write the `line` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `"\n"`. [\n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is an special character that represents a line jump.

Comment: Thanks, I already read about that. But did not understand how to specify it to add the empty line after a certain line. Can you help me with that?